# Multi file upload and download MEAN stack app

Tags: node.js, angular

I'm new in nodejs and angular and trying to create a page that users can upload multi-file from frontend to backend and then retrieve data with images.

sending data to the backend is absolutely fine but retrieving data ***with files*** to front end doesn't work and I lost in google for three days and no luck so far to find any start point.
any help will be grateful

Comment: What you mean by retrieving data with files not working . Show your code for better understanding

Comment: Ok. I have an app that manages products which have multiple attached images and pdf or word docs. now I can retrieve product name and price but cannot retrieve attached files.

Comment: Show your code for retrieving data for files?